# EKS 1.11 and HPA

Tags: amazon-eks

Now EKS supports two kubernetes version [1.10 and 1.11](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/platform-versions.html).

1.10 starts to support HPA since platform version eks.2.
1.11 is new, now only has eks.1, I cannot find any reference if HPA is supported now. Does anyone know if it HPA is supported or have tried using HPA with 1.11?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HPA is supported for 1.11 and I have been using it for a while using the tutorial [here](https://eksworkshop.com/scaling/deploy_hpa/).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without helm?